# How to prevent my code from modifying or copying

Tags: javascript, php, validation, cakephp, master-pages

I develop a small website now some of my friends asking to give us the code.so i want now to do a trick in my code that no one can copy or modify my code.if any one know's please post.

Comment: Send them a photo of your code :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Copy:** Forget it. If you give the code to someone, he can just copy and re-use it. Consider using an appropriate license for your code to make shure the receiver knows what he is allowed to do with your code

**Changes:** Use a version control system. As a developer you must learn to use at least one. Do it now. I recommend `git`, but there are plenty of VCS`ses available (svn,bazaar,cvs...)

Comment: so with the help of  git i can prevent my code from others to modify..?

Comment: No, but you can make the changes visible. You can do a `diff` between your released code and what you are expect to be changed code from you and can see the changes. Or, better, let your clients use your code repo (readonly) to checkout the code. Then they have a working copy. If they mess around, they cannot pull updates without conflicts. If they solve conflicts, you still see it in the working copies history. Plus, delivering new code to the customer becomes more easy.